# Error al llenar un state dentro de uno de los filtros de react(map)

Tags: reactjs, bucles, react-hooks

Lo que quiero hacer es llenar un state de react js , dentro de un map....
Lo q pasa es que solo se llena con solo dato(es como si solo recorreria una vez por renderizado...)
Estuve probando varias maneras, pero no funciona nada, alguien sabra si se puede hacer de otra manera?
Aca les dejo el codigo..
-TipoProducto es una state q se guarda un arreglo(Viene de un context) se tendria q repetir 5 veces..

```
  const [dataS, setDataS]=useState([])//Se multiplica por 5 datos (Productos vendidos)
  const obteniendoDatos=async()=>{
TipoProducto.map(t=>{
 
  setDataS([ ...dataS , {label: t.nombre, data : [2,5,6,5,7,4,8,2,1,6,9,4] } ]) 
 })  
console.log(dataS)    
 } 
  useEffect(async() => {
obteniendoDatos()

 
 
  }, []);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir de dónde sale `TipoProducto`? (La manera correcta de incluir esta información es **editando** tu pregunta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacer un setState dentro de una ciclo es considerado una mala práctica pues conlleva múltiples renders del componente. Por lo que  l solución a tu problema es hacer el setState una única vez.

El siguiente código debería ayudarte:

```
const [dataS, setDataS] = useState([])
const obteniendoDatos = async () => {
    setDataS(prevData => prevData.concat(
        TipoProducto.map(t => ({
            label:  t.nombre,
            data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4, 8, 2, 1,  6, 9, 4]
        }))
    )) 
} 
useEffect(() => {
    obteniendoDatos()
}, [])
```

Esto siempre y cuando ‘TipoProducto.map(...)’ funcione igual que el ‘.map(...)’ del prototype Array